# Can't deal with path

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, path

I need to load the profile in Chrome using Python Selenium Webdriver.
Everyting works fine when I use the direct path like this:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\path_to_folder_with_myprogram_user_data_folder_is_aready_there\User Data")
```

But I plan to use my code on several different PC, so my program should detect the path. I need to detect and insert path to this part of code:

```
options.add_argument("user-data-dir=C:\\Path") #Path to my user data folder which is in my program folder
```

I have a problem because I don't know how to get the path from the variable and insert it in 'user-data-dir= '. The variable "user_data_dir" contains the correct path, but when I'm trying to use it, the quotes ruins everything. Without the quotes it works neither.

```
options = Options()    
user_data_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'User Data')
print (user_data_dir)
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir=user_data_dir') 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(retval, 'webdrivers\chromedriver.exe'), options=options)
```

Comment: Are you trying to set user dir? Are you not able to concat strings? myPath = "c:/mypath"
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir='+myPath)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this,

```
options = Options()    
user_data_dir = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)), 'User Data')
print (user_data_dir)
options.add_argument(r'user-data-dir='+user_data_dir) 
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path=os.path.join(retval, 'webdrivers\chromedriver.exe'), options=options)
```